# integral of special derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

Assume that $S(0)>=0, I_w(0)>=0, I(0)>=0$ and $F(t)=\mu+\beta_1\frac{I_W(t)}{N}+\beta_2 \frac{I(t)}{N}$(where $\mu, \beta_1,\beta_2$ and N are constants).
If we have that:

$\frac{d}{dt}\{S(t)exp(\int_0^t F(s)ds)\}>=0$, can(by integrating) we conclude that $S(t)>=0$ or $S(t)>0$?
We also have followings:

$\frac{dS(t)}{dt}=\lambda_1-\mu S(t)-\beta_1 \frac{S(t)I_W(t)}{N}-\beta_2\frac{S(t)I(t)}{N},\\
\frac{dI_W(t)}{dt}=\lambda_2+\beta_1 \frac{S(t)I_W(t)}{N}+\beta_2\frac{S(t)I(t)}{N}-(\mu+\alpha_1+\alpha_2)I_W(t),\\
\frac{dI(t)}{dt}=\lambda_3+\alpha_1I_W(t)-(\mu+\alpha_3)I(t).
 $

Thanks  for any help.

Comment: Assuming that $S(t) = 0$ identically, I don't see any contradiction. But we don't know if there is a link between $S, I_w, I, F$...

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the question.

Comment: With the modified question, if $\lambda_1 > 0$, you now have $\frac{d}{d t}\{\ldots\} > 0$, hence $S(t)>0$ for $t>0$.

Comment: But how? How did you get the result so quickly? Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation of the system can be written $\frac{d S(t)}{d t} + F(t)S(t)= \lambda_1$. Multiplying by $\exp(\int_0^t F(s) d s)$ one gets, assuming $\lambda_1 > 0$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d t}\left\{S(t)e^{\int_0^t F(s) d s}\right\} = \lambda_1 e^{\int_0^t F(s) d s}> 0
\end{equation}
Hence $\varphi(t) = S(t)e^{\int_0^t F(s) d s}$ increases strictly with time and $\varphi(0) \ge 0$. It follows that $\varphi(t)>0$ for $t>0$, hence also $S(t)> 0$.